# SignalR reconnect causes memory leak

Tags: signalr, signalr.client

We have got a memory leak problem suspecting SignalR.  We added Appinsight to our project ans got a report like this. What does this reconnect mean ?

[image]

Comment: We have similar issue. Got 256MB of `Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.Context` objects. With `reconnect` request waiting for long, >3 hours. Have you found resolution for this?

Comment: I have the same problem in 2019. We need a proper guide on handling reconnection.

Answer (score 0):

The /reconnect request is very similar to the /connect request, but it is used after the client has already connected and then becomes disconnected for some reason. As with the /connect request, the response to the reconnect request can remain open until the SignalR connection is closed.

SignalR will try to automatically reconnect to the server after the connection goes down until the DisconnectTimeout (which is 30 seconds by default) is reached. During this time period, SignalR will make /reconnect requests on an interval until one of them succeeds. If no reconnect request succeeds before the timeout, the SignalR client will transition to the disconnected state.

[Understanding and Handling Connection Lifetime Events in SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events)

Comment: We are using the Servicebus to scaleout our systems. Now I am investigating on that. Maybe that's the source of the leak.